# inline block vertical alignment issue

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have 4 boxes in my page and all the boxes has `display: inline-block;`. The problem is with vertical align, all these boxes content is dynamic so one box might have more rows than the other for different users.

[image: screen shot]
Please advise on how can I avoid the vertical gap for Audit Administration box.

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Arial';
    font-size: 12px;
}

a,
a:link,
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: blue;
    background-color: transparent;
}

a:visited {
    color: purple;
    background-color: transparent;
}

a:hover,
.ui-state-hover a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<body style="padding-left:20px;width:70%">
    <br/>
    <div style="padding-top: 1em;">
        <div style="display: inline-block; width: 300px;  vertical-align:top; ">
            <div>
                <div id="id61">
                    <div>
                        <div class="ui-widget">
                            <div class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
                                <div style="padding: .25em; text-align: center; ">
                                    <label>My Audits Summary</label> (<a href="javascript:;" id="id56">Refresh</a>) </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                                <div style="padding: .25em;">
                                    <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="javascript:;" id="id57">
                                                <span>Review New Audit Assignment from Audit Liaison  (1)</span>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="javascript:;" id="id58">
                                                <span>Assign Audit Analyst to Audit Recommendation Code  (1)</span>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="javascript:;" id="id59">
                                                <span>Perform Audit Assignment  (8)</span>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="javascript:;" id="id5a">
                                                <span>Review Returned ARP  (1)</span>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div style="display: inline-block; width: 350px;  vertical-align:top;">
            <div>

                <div>

                    <div class="ui-widget  ui-corner-all">
                        <div class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
                            <div style="padding: .25em;">
                                <span>Overdue Rec code Actions Summary <span>(<a href="javascript:;" id="id5b">Refresh</a>) </span> </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-widget-content  ui-corner-all">
                            <div style="padding: 5px;">
                                <div id="id62">
                                    <span>No items found.</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>








            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="display: inline-block;  width: 100px;  vertical-align: top;">

            <div class="ui-widget">
                <div class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
                    <div style="text-align: center; padding: .25em;">
                        <label>Find Audit</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                    <div>
                        <ul style="margin: 0;">
                            <li>
                                <a href="javascript:;" id="id35"><span>Rejected</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul style="margin: 0;">
                            <li>
                                <a href="javascript:;" id="id36"><span>Pending</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul style="margin: 0;">
                            <li>
                                <a href="javascript:;" id="id37"><span>Closed</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>

        <div style="display: inline-block; width: 200px; vertical-align: top;">
            <div class="ui-widget">
                <div class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
                    <div style="text-align: center; padding: .25em;">
                        <label>Reports</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                    <div style="padding: .25em">
                        <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                            <li>
                                <a href="javascript:;" id="id38"><span>Audit Tracking by Program office Report</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                            <li>
                                <a href="javascript:;" id="id39"><span>Audit Tracking Report by FY-Quarter Report</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                            <li>
                                <a href="javascript:;" id="id3a"><span>Audit Workflow Bottleneck Report</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                            <li>
                                <a href="javascript:;" id="id3b"><span>Audit Actions Report</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                            <li>
                                <a href="javascript:;" id="id3c"><span>Stewardship Report 4</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                            <li>
                                <a href="javascript:;" id="id3d"><span>Disallowance Report</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                            <li>
                                <a href="javascript:;" id="id3e"><span>Audit Summary Report by CO and RO</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                            <li>
                                <a href="javascript:;" id="id3f"><span>Recommendation Code Summary Report by CO and RO</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                            <li>
                                <a href="javascript:;" id="id40"><span>Recommendation Code Summary Report by Program Office</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; width: 200px; ">
            <div>
                <div class="ui-widget">
                    <div class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
                        <div style="text-align: center; padding: .25em;">
                            <label>Audit Administration</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                        <div style="padding: .25em">
                            <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:;" id="id41"><span>Audit Data Preparation and Processing</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:;" id="id42"><span>My Monitored Audits</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:;" id="id43"><span>Audit Logging and Maintenance</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:;" id="id44"><span>Audit Amendment</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:;" id="id45"><span>Reset Audit &amp; Assignments</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:;" id="id46"><span>Archive Audit</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:;" id="id47"><span>Reassign Official</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:;" id="id48"><span>Reassign Recommendation Codes</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:;" id="id49"><span>Grantee Name and Address Maintenance</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:;" id="id4a"><span>Attach Document to Audit</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:;" id="id4b"><span>My Delegated Authority</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:;" id="id4c"><span>Delegate Account Access</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:;" id="id4d"><span>My Open Audits</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:;" id="id4e"><span>Users</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:;" id="id4f"><span>Program-Organization</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:;" id="id50"><span>User Assistants</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:;" id="id51"><span>User Reports</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:;" id="id52"><span>Batch Reassignments</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:;" id="id53"><span>Overdue Rec Codes Status Tracking</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:;" id="id54"><span>Document Library</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:;" id="id55"><span>Fac Data</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[Link to JSBin output](http://output.jsbin.com/yogotanoba)

Comment: if you want to fit <div> wherever there is sufficient space then you might want to look into jquery masonry..

Comment: ^ What you're looking for is called the Masonry layout and is commonly achieved with JS libraries. I think you may be able to do it with CSS Flexbox, though... I'm not sure as I've never tried.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal behavior when you use `display: inline-block`

You might be interested about `columns` use :

```
div {
    -webkit-columns: 3;
    -moz-columns: 3;
    columns: 3;
}

div p { 
    background: red; 
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
}
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/grNUC/70/)

**Compatibility** : http://caniuse.com/#search=column

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I can't see the error, I think that it is a problem of the resolution of your computer or the size of the monitor.

I would recommend you the bootstrap framework, it is really easy to use and it will help you a lot for that kind of situations

Comment: This is to do with the element layout of the page, nothing to-do with resolution. And I don't believe bootstrap has anything to cater for this sort of dynamic layout.